# how to create pdf from .cshtml (razor) Template in c# console application

Tags: c#, pdf, razor, console-application

tried with bellow NuGet package to achieve the task of creating pdf from HTML razor template in the c# console application , but failed

1. RazorPDF
2. iTextSharp
3. Rotativa

is it possible in a console application with above NuGet package ?

Comment: It's possible with Rotativa. Probably with all though, as long as they are using the render engine from .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used Apache FOP its working fine